# Capybara feature test ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Using Rspec and Capybara for feature testing. Unfortunately, I'm running into problems...

**basic_interaction_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe "basic interaction" do 
    before :each do
        category = build_stubbed(:category, name: "Pants")
    end
    
    it "displays category" do
        visit("/")
        click_link("Pants")
        expect(current_path).to eq("pants")
        expect(page).to have_title("Pants | app_name")
    end
end
```

Results in

```
Failure/Error: <li><%= link_to category.name, products_path(category_or_product: category.slug) %></li>
     
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

**homepage_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @categories = []
    Category.root_order.each do |category_name|
      @categories << Category.find_by(name: category_name)
end
```

Can you guys see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why the problem occurred.

Forgot about the method in the category model which ensures that only the top-level categories are displayed on the homepage.

```
  def self.root_order
    %w[Tops Outerwear Pants Suits Shoes]
  end
```

This caused a problem when not all top categories were created. With the following fixtures the test pass.

```
    before :each do
      category1 = create(:category, name: "Tops")
      category2 = create(:category, name: "Outerwear")
      category3 = create(:category, name: "Pants")
      category4 = create(:category, name: "Suits")
      category5 = create(:category, name: "Shoes")
    end
```

Comment: Since you don't need to actually access category1..5 in your test scenarios just do something like `%w[Tops Outerwear Pants Suits Shoes].each { |n| create(:category, name: n) }` rather than creating 5 unused variables and repeating code - or better yet setup seeding for your DB if those categories are always required to be there

Comment: Sound like a good idea! Will seed it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

When writing feature specs you can't use `build_stubbed` for records you want your app to be able to access. Assuming the `category` you're building in the `before` block is what you're expecting the app to display on the page, you need to actually create the record because the app is accessing it via a DB query.

```
before :each do
    category = create(:category, name: "Pants")
end
```

Beyond that, you should never be using basic RSpec matchers (`eq`, etc) with Capybara objects, instead you should be using the Capybara provided matchers which take care of the asynchronous nature of tests using a browser by providing waiting/retrying behavior. So instead of

```
expect(current_path).to eq("pants")
```

you should have something like

```
expect(page).to have_current_path("pants")
```

Comment: I see. I've changed build_stubbed to create and replaced the RSpec matcher with the Capybara one but still, the same error is present.

Comment: @JonasFagerlund then you have an error in your app. ‘category` in your view is nil, but you don’t show enough info to see where it’s actually coming from

Comment: You're right! Figured out the problem and summarized it in an answer.